# Syntax highlighting - help me find the bug

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, syntax

I have a bug and I can't figure out the solution. Perhaps you esteemed folk can be of aid.

I want to extend a syntax file (julia syntax in polyglot package). I want to include the following patterns

```
"\::\zs\w*\ze"
"\^\s*function \zs\w*\ze\("
```

The first is intended to match words following ::. The second is intended to match the function name foo in an expression like

```
function foo(bar)
```

In my .vim/after/syntax/julia.vim, I write

```
syntax match juliaCustomType "\v::\zs\w*\ze" display
syntax match juliaFunctionName "\v^\s*function \zs.*\ze\(" display

highlight def link juliaCustomType Constant
highlight def link juliaFunctionName Function
```

And this works if I disable vim-polyglot and the julia-vim packages, the ones providing julia syntax support. If I add either of them back, it no longer works.

I add both the custom groups to the relevant syntax cluster `juliaExpressions`, which is the one that is allowed to be contained in other regions everywhere. I check this by making a mock syn match like this `syntax match juliaCustomType "foobar"` and see that it highlights inside syntax regions.

Now if I remove `\zs` and `\ze` from the `::`matching, it works but highlights the :: which I don't want. The second expression, I believe has some problems because of how `function` is handled in this line from the package syntax file:

```
let s:nodot = '\%(\.\)\@'.s:d(1).'1<!'
exec 'syntax region juliaFunctionBlock matchgroup=juliaBlKeyword start="'.s:nodot.'\<function\>" end="'.s:nodot.'\<end\>" contains=@juliaExpressions fold'
```

But I can't for the life of me figure out what the problem is. Any help or suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Try the following: Replace all double quotes (`"`) in the `syntax match` lines with single quotes (`'`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It didn't work immediately, but I'll try more iterations similar tries to see if the encapsulation could be the problem. That hadn't really been considered yet!

Comment: Read help on “string” and “literal-string”